# Apache VirtualHost: Different IP(Different NIC), Same Port won't work

Tags: apache-2.2

I want apache to serve differnt cert to a different network.

```
Listen 192.168.X.5:443 #WAN
Listen 192.168.Y.5:443 #Network

<VirtualHost 192.168.X.5:443>
    ServerName ssl.mydomain.us
    DocumentRoot "C:/Same/Html/htdocs/"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache/conf/sslP/PUBLIC.key" # I'll call this "WAN Cert"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache/conf/sslP/PUBLIC.crt"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache/conf/sslP/PUBLIC.ca"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.Y.5:443>
    ServerName ssl.mydomain.us #--- sorry, I can't, I don't want to change this
    DocumentRoot "C:/Same/Html/htdocs/"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache/conf/ssl/NETWORK.key" # I'll call this "Network cert"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache/conf/ssl/NETWORK.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I connect via other internet(connect X.5): WAN Cert used [OK]
When I connect from network(connect Y.5): WAN Cert used [WHY?]

The question is:
Why Network cert won't used when I connect from network?
And how do I fix this?
(Of course I connect to 192.168.Y.5, not X.5)

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance have the `NameVirtualHost *:443` in your configuration?
In this case apache will use the first ssl cert to establish the connection.

See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Is the CN of NETWORK.crt the same as the CN of PUBLIC.crt?

Try this from a client that you want to connect to 192.168.Y.5 run (you may have to install openssl - if you only have win boxes, then cygwin has openssl - I'm not sure if you can get it as a standalone app/lib):

```
nslookup ssl.mydomain.us    
openssl s_client -connect ssl.mydomain.us:443
```

Then run the same command from a client that you want to connect to 192.168.X.5.
Paste the results into the question.